# Pass a valid time type usnig moment from React setState to postgres

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, momentjs

I am new in coding and essentially in React. I am trying to create a human resource management system that will have an employee and an admin. I am now working on using an axios to post to knex postgres as db and nodejs.

I need help to pass in a correct value with format of "HH:mm:ss" to my backend taking time type.

This is my knex migration:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('undertime_overtime', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.date('date_filed').notNullable(); //has to be default date now?
        table.time('from_time').notNullable();
        table.time('to_time').notNullable();
        table.string('reason').notNullable();
        table.integer('time_type').defaultTo(1);
        table.boolean('isDeleted').defaultTo(0);
        table.boolean('isAccepted').defaultTo(0);
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        table.timestamp('modified_at').defaultTo(null);
        table.integer('created_by').unsigned().notNullable();

        table.foreign('created_by').references('employees.id');

    });
```

Here are the things I tried that did not work:

```
state = {
    date_filed: new Date(),
    from_time: moment().format("HH:mm:ss").toString(),
    to_time: moment().format("HH:mm:ss"),
    reason: '',
    time_type: 1,
    created_by: 1 //todo
    };
```

```
handleFromTime = time => {
    this.setState({
        from_time: time.format("HH:mm:ss")
    });
    console.log(time("HH:mm:ss"));
  };
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Content, Row, Col, Box, Button } from 'adminlte-2-react';
import TimePicker from 'rc-time-picker';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import axios from 'axios'


import 'rc-time-picker/assets/index.css';

class OvertimeComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    date_filed: new Date(),
    from_time: moment(),
    to_time: moment(),
    reason: '',
    time_type: 1,
    created_by: 1 //todo
    };

  handleChangeDateFiled = date => {
    this.setState({
      date_filed: date
    });
    console.log(date)
  };

  handleFromTime = time => {
    this.setState({
        from_time: time
    });
    console.log(time);
  };

  handleToTime = time => {
    this.setState({
        to_time: time
    });
    console.log(time.format('HH:mm:ss'));
  };

  handleReason = event => {
    this.setState({
      reason: event.target.value
    })
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    console.log(`date-> ${this.state.date_filed} from ${this.state.from_time} to ${this.state.to_time} reason ${this.state.reason}`)
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/time',this.state)
    .then(response=> {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    })
  }

  footer = [
    <Button key="btnSubmit" type="success" pullRight text="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />, 
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <Content title="Overtime" subTitle="Requests" browserTitle="Overtime">
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Row> 
              <Col xs={12}>
                <Box title="Overtime Application" type="primary" collapsable footer={this.footer}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Date</label>
                      <div>
                        <DatePicker name="date_filed" selected={this.state.date_filed} onChange={this.handleChangeDateFiled}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>From</label>
                        <div>
                          <TimePicker name="from_time" value={this.state.from_time} onChange={this.handleFromTime} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>To</label>
                      <div>
                        <TimePicker name="to_time" value={this.state.to_time} onChange={this.handleToTime} />
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Reason</label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="reason" value={this.state.reason} onChange={this.handleReason} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter ..." />
                    </div>
                  </Box>
                </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>

          <Col md={6}>
            <Box title="Request Status" type="primary" collapsable>
              <div className="form-group">
                  <label>todo</label>
              </div>
            </Box>
          </Col>
        </Row>
    </Content>);
  }
}

export default OvertimeComponent;
```

Comment: Hi there! So I'm trying to figure out where the problem is. Is it the time format conversion in the react code? Or you get error when you send the data to the backend?

Comment: Hello there! I get an error when I send the data to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I should've touched the axios post to get the format I wanted from the moment object.

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/time',{
      'date_filed':this.state.date_filed,
      'from_time':this.state.from_time.format('HH:mm:ss'),
      'to_time':this.state.to_time.format('HH:mm:ss'),
      'reason':this.state.reason,
      'created_by': 1 //todo
    })
```